# AWS elastic beanstalk configuration for rolling updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

Currently I'm trying to solve some mystery changing settings in an Elastic Beanstalk environment. I will try to explain the situation and what is happening.

We have a Jenkins server which we can command to create a build (artifact) to upload to an S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is watched by a cloudwatch event what will trigger a codepipeline and deploys the artifact to multiple ec2 instances.

Now on the EBS environment there are some settings, for example the rolling updates part. It seems that sometimes the DeploymentPolicy is 'magically' updated from rolling to allAtOnce. Me and my colleagues don't understand how this setting is changed, because no-one touches this part of the gui.

I've tried putting these settings into config files, but that didn't work out so well. I tried adding a env.yaml in the project root. The EBS is reading this file, but I get errors that the syntax is incorrect. I tried following this document, but I can't get it to work.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-manifest.html

Also I tried adding a file in `.ebextensions/rolling_updates.config` with the following content:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    BatchSizeType: Percentage
    DeploymentPolicy: Immutable
```

But that also didn't work. (I tried some other values just to check if the update worked)

Is there somebody who has done this before and can help me explain what I should do to fix this?

One thought that has crossed my mind is putting a config file in an S3 bucket and install AWS-cli on the Jenkins server. Then every deployment we can update the EBS config before uploading the artifact to S3. But I'm not sure that's a correct approach as well.

Thanks all!

Comment: `Immutable` is not rolling. Not really sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to test if the config file was read correct and the settings were updated. What we would like to achieve is that the EBS setting, now specific the `Rolling updates and deployments` part, are configured in files that are stored somewhere (git or S3) and when we update this file the settings in EBS automatically change.

Comment: Only you know your CodePipiline and Jenkins setup, with all associated code. Must be bug somewhere. Without full details of your setup, all the config files, its difficult to speculate.

Comment: Our Jenkins is very simple. It does a checkout from bitbucket, it creates a zip and uploads this to an S3 bucket. It does not have any further config files. The CodePipeline is also really simple, it is just a connection between the S3 bucket and an Elastic Beanstalk environment. To my further notice there is not much config involved.

I'm wondering if it is possible to change EBS config in this way as the artefacts are deployed to EC2 instances and EBS is the parent of the EC2 instances. Initially we configured the EBS by the GUI, but would really like to move the settings to a file.